# How to check whether a string is a valid UUID?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, uuid, ecto

I'm using Phoenix and Ecto. In a model I have a UUID field. In some cases I'll need to check whether a string that comes from a user is a proper UUID. How to do it?

I've checked out https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.UUID.html but based on the decription I haven't found a proper function that appears to be the one I'd use in my case.

How to do it?

Comment: have you tried using cast/1? it should return a invalid changeset if that is not a valid uuid

Comment: @Daniel now yes, Mr. Matushkin the 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

`Ecto` itself would use [`dump/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html#c:dump/1) to convert to the native [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) type.

`cast/1` suggested by @Daniel is almost what you need, but it’d accept *raw UUID* as well, what, as I understood from the task description, is not expected.

That said, `match?({:ok, _}, Ecto.UUID.dump(input))` is your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using UUID dep you can check it with `UUID.info/1` function, ie:

```
UUID.info("58b784e4-a3cd-4880-8629-a481f017c4c")
```

Will return:

```
{:error, "Invalid argument; Not a valid UUID: 58b784e4-a3cd-4880-8629-a481f017c4c"}
```